# Alias path name in VS Code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I have a folder structure as

```
└── project
    ├── package1
    │   ├── module1.py
    │   └── module2.py
    └── package2
        ├── __init__.py
        └── module3.py
```

From module1.py I can currently import something from module3.py with `from package2.module3 import abc`. However I want to alias `package2` as something else without changing the name of the folder so that I can write `from new_name.module3 import abc` and I want VS Code to recognize the import path.

Comment: there's no way to do this. python is not able to handle aliases. however you can import a  module this way: `import package2 as new_name`

Comment: @sevy If we disregard python. Can VS Code handle this?

Comment: VSC is an editor it has no knowledge of any language and all behavior is handled by extensions, this is done by the Python extension

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add a module `new_name` (i.e. a file `new_name.py`) with the following content:

```py
__path__ = [
    "package2",
]
```

For more info, see [Packages and the role of **path**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/#packages-and-the-role-of-path).